# Javasript websocket.send sends [Object object]

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a requirement, where I need to send all user actions in browser to a remote application. Like user hits a link, types in textfield / textarea, selects a choice etc. On browser side I am using Javascript to listen to events and then sending those to remove application using websocket. My code looks as below.

```
var sock = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.2:8082", "tci"); 

function user_intercept_click_event(e)
{
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    sock.send(target);
    console.log(target);
}

function user_intercept_key_press(e)
{
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    sock.send(target);
    console.log(target);
}

if(document.addEventListener) 
{
    document.addEventListener('click', user_intercept_click_event);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', user_intercept_key_press);
} 
else if(document.attachEvent) 
{
    document.attachEvent('onclick', user_intercept_click_event);
    document.attachEvent('onkeypress', user_intercept_key_press);
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) 
{
    sock.close();
    return null;
}
```

Let's say I click on a textfield with id as endpoints1, then
the console log prints proper value, like[image]

Where as in remote application I get 
**[object HTMLInputElement]**

I want to get complete string as printed in console log in remote application. How can I get it? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: you'll probably need the `.value` or `.textContent` of ``e.target` - depending on what type of element it is - as far as keypress goes ... well, you'll want the value of the key maybe? rather than an html element

Comment: @JaromandaX is right, you can't send entire HTML elements on a websockets. You can only send strings.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks. The target.outerHTML has HTML content, and for keypress target.value has the complete value.

Comment: it's up to you what you send, just make sure its text, not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sock.send(target.outerHTML);
```

Comment: As you can see in comment section in question, outerHTML is the right element to be sent over socket. I am accepting your answer.